# StreamWriter is writing carriage returns?

Tags: c#

I have a very simple console application that creates a text file. Below is a recap of the code:

```
StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("c:\\temp.txt");
foreach (blah...)
{
  writer.Write(body.ToString() + "\n");
  writer.Flush();
}
writer.Close();
```

The client is claiming there are carriage returns at the end of each line. Where are these carriage returns coming from?

**Update:** After opening in VS binary editor and Notepad++, there were no occurrences of `0d 0a`. I'm going to go back to the client.

Comment: What are they using to read the files to check this?

Comment: You say "the client is claiming..."  Have you checked yourself?

Comment: Dan, what is a good utility for viewing these special chars?

Comment: use Notepad++. Go to View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters

Comment: Can you post more code so we can get a sense of context?

Comment: I was getting the same thing using WriteLine instead of Write... thanks for teaching me Write it's what i was after. otherwise WriteLine adds a return after every string. other than that writeline is the same as write on my pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file in the Visual Studio binary editor (File.Open.File, click down-arrow on Open button, choose Open With... and pick Binary Editor), and look for `0D` bytes. If none are present, then either:

- your client can't tell the the difference between a line feed and a carriage return,
- your transmission method is modifying the file en-route. Is there any FTP binary/ascii mismatch going on?

If there *are* `0D` bytes, then they are present in your `body` variable.

Comment: Or the client is opening the file with a tool/function that automatically replaces \n with \r\n. Many Windows text editors do so.

Comment: This is good. I did find the occurrence of 0d 0a between lines when opened in the VS binary editor but not with Notepad++. So it must exist in the body variable? I'll update my original post w/ the code.

Comment: FYI, the client didn't know what they were talking about since the file did not have any carriage returns.

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code.

[alt text http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/5443/18414385.png](http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/5443/18414385.png)

The code you posted does not have any carriage returns (`0D`) only new lines (`0A`). Something else is creating the carriage returns or the client does not know what a carriage return really is.

Answer (score 1):

The `"\n"` at the end of each `write` call

**EDIT:** I know this is a new line, not a carriage return but I bet any money the client is getting confused between the two and it's actually this that is causing the problem

Comment: That's a line feed, not a carriage return.

Comment: `\n` is a line feed. `\r` is carriage return.

Comment: @BoltClock, @ChrisF - I know, but unless there is a carraige return at the end of the body, this'll be what the client is complaining about

Comment: the "\n" will create a new line in the text file and this will be what the client is complaining about.

Comment: How do you write a new line without the "\n"?

Comment: You can't, I would go back to the client, explain the situation and find out why it is causing a problem before you try to fix it

Answer (score 1):

In your code you put a line feed (\n).

Your customer is talking about a carriage return (\r). Maybe your customer is taking a line feed per a carriage return ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the client distinguish between a CR and LF? Is the flush() necessary? Are you overloading the buffer if you don't flush?

Unless you have a massive amount of text you might find more use out of creating a StringBuilder to format the text exactly as you want it with \n, \r, \t or whatever and then pumping that directly into a StreamWriter.

Answer (score 0):

If each `body` string's first character was '\r', it would explain what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether `body` is also ending with characters you don't want printed? This is the other potential problem source.